# Discord rate limiting while only sending 1 request per minute

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to display the amount of people that are online on my minecraft server by naming a closed voice channel the amount of people online. I initially wanted to check every 60 seconds and update the voice channel if something has changed. I got the program up and running pretty quickly with discord.py but then it pretty quickly gave me the error message

> WARNING  discord.http We are being rate limited. PATCH https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/*** responded with 429.

It consistently gives me this error after I send my 5th request.
I don't know if this is because you can only update the name of a voice channel 5 times per 600 seconds or if I am doing something wrong.
Here is my code:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(int(CHANNEL_ID))
    update_info.start(channel)


@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def update_info(channel):
    global LastUpdate
    players_online = get_info(HOST, PORT)['players']['online']
    if players_online != LastUpdate:
        print("updating")
        await channel.edit(name=f"Users Online:  {players_online}")
        LastUpdate = players_online

client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reviewing the Discord API documentation that describes its [rate limits](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#header-format-rate-limit-header-examples). You are receiving a `429` HTTP response (AKA - too many requests).

Either the API you are using to manipulate your Minecraft server is returning the `429`, or Discord's API is.

You should try to review the full rate limit header response (see link), to get a better idea of the source of the issue. It's hard to tell from the information/code provided.

Comment: I tried clicking the link discord.py provided but i get the following error: {"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0},  Is there a way to resolve this error? It's also definitely discord's api that is returning this error message as I am not using an api to query the minecraft data. I have also previously visited the website you provided but I don't really see an answer for why I am being rate limited as it states you are able to send 50 request per seconds and I am sending 1 per minute.

Comment: @SebastiaanTheCoder I am not extremely familiar with the Discord API - but that link does not go anywhere. The 401 is a red-herring. Don't focus too much on that. Edit: I would recommend adding logging and seeing for yourself if it's making as many calls as you think.

Comment: I added a logger and I am really just sending 1 request per iteration. I also figured out how to get the full rate limit header response and It says I have 49 left out off the 50 but discord.py still says I am rate limited and the changes I am trying to make are not going threw. I even tried rewriting a short demo in javascript to see if it was just a problem in discord.py but I got the same result. I presume there is just a cap on how often you can change the name of a channel in discord. Thanks for all the help non the less